# Dojo callback before AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo, callback

Does Dojo [xhrPost](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/xhrPost.html) / [xhrGet](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/xhrGet.html) has an equivalent callback function as jQuery [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dojo/aspect`.

```
aspect.before(dojo, "xhrGet", function(args){
    args.url = 'index.html?TEST';
    return [args];
});

var btn = new Button({label: 'xhr'}, 'btn');
on(btn, 'click', function(evt){
    var xhrArgs = {
        url: "index.html",
        handleAs: "text",
        load: function(data){ console.debug(data); },
        error: function(error){ console.error(error);}
    }
    dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
});
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/aspect.html